# Simulating a mixture model in time series

Tags: r, time-series, simulation, autoregressive

Let $\Phi (\cdot)$ be the cdf of the standard normal distribution. Given $(y_t)_{t \in \mathbb N}$ a time series. Suppose $F(y_t | \mathcal{F}_{t-1})$ is the conditional
cumulative distribution function of $y_t$ given the past information, evaluated at $y_t$, where $\mathcal{F}_t$ is the information set up to time $t$.

I would like to simulate the following model:

\begin{equation}
F(y_t | \mathcal{F}_{t-1}) = 0.75 \, \Phi \left(\frac{y_t- 0.5 \, y_{t-1} }{5.0}\right) + 0.25 \, \Phi \left(\frac{y_t- 0.4 \, y_{t-1} }{1.0}\right)
\end{equation}

Note that defining $u_t = \frac{y_t- 0.5 \, y_{t-1} }{5.0} $ and $v_t = \frac{y_t- 1.4 \, y_{t-1} }{1.0} $, we have
\begin{equation}\label{AR123}\tag I
y_t =  0.5 y_{t-1} + 5 u_t, \quad u_{t} \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1) 
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{AR1234}\tag{II}
y_t =  0.4 y_{t-1} + v_t, \quad v_{t} \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1) 
\end{equation}
At first I thought this was to draw a Bernoulli(0.75) and then choose a realization of (\ref{AR123}) or (\ref{AR1234}):

```
# My function simulating an AR
ar_sim = function(n, a, b) {
  # Normal errors 
  e = b*rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1)
  # my simulation
  x = rep(0,n)
  for (t in 2:n)
  {
    x[t] = a*x[t-1] + e[t]
  }
  return(x)
}

# Size of my sample
T = 1000
# Bernoulli
d  = sample(c(1,0), 1, prob=c(0.75,0.25))
if (d==1) {
  x = ar_sim(T,.5, 10)
}  else{
  x = ar_sim(T,0.4, 1)
  
}
ts.plot(x)
```

But I believe I'm making mistakes in this simulation. Could you help me to do the simulation correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This principle is correct: at each iteration, generate an independent Bernoulli $e_t\in(0,1)$ that determines the coefficients of the autoregression:
$$x_t=a[e_t]x_{t-1}+b[e_t]\epsilon_t\qquad\epsilon_t\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$$
Your R code is not implementing this generation correctly:

```
d  = sample(c(1,0), 1, prob=c(0.75,0.25))
```

does not modify `d` at each value of `t`